# Convert horizontal values into a vertical column, pasted one after another in R

Tags: r

I'm working on r. I would like to ask for help converting my df into a different df1 to work with it: The current df look like this:

```
|--------|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Entity | ID | Category1 | Category2 | Category3 |
|--------|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   AB   | 01 |     00    |     01    |     01    |
|   AC   | 02 |     00    |     01    |     00    |
|--------|----|-----------|-----------|-----------|

I need to convert it in something like this:

Entity ID  Categories  Value
AB     01  Category1     00
AB     01  Category2     01
AB     01  Category3     01
AC     02  Category1     00
AC     02  Category2     01
AC     02  Category3     00
```

The transposing function does not help because as you can see I need the categories to be copied vertically one after the other. I really need help with this as my df is extremely big to do it manually, and I would highly appreciate your help R community. Please!!

**Data in `dput` format**

```
data <-
structure(list(Entity = c("AB", "AC"), ID = c(1, 2), Category1 = c(0, 
0), Category2 = c(1, 1), Category3 = c(1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
#   Entity ID Category1 Category2 Category3
# 1     AB 01        00        01        01
# 2     AC 02        00        01        00
```

You can do:

```
library(tidyr)

gather(data, key = "Category", value = "Value", Category1, Category2, Category3)

#   Entity ID  Category Value
# 1     AB 01 Category1    00
# 2     AC 02 Category1    00
# 3     AB 01 Category2    01
# 4     AC 02 Category2    01
# 5     AB 01 Category3    01
# 6     AC 02 Category3    00
```

where `data` is your data frame.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working, I'm super grateful for your so super-fast help. Thank you count orlok you did my day, I have been struggling with this like crazy. Thank you!